# Debugger problem at C# Express - 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, debugging

I'm living a debugger problem at C# Express Edition - 2008. After modifying in code, I run the debugger. Unfortunately, the last modification are not be processed. After I exit C# and then run again it, when I load the code and run the debugger, the last modification are processed by the debugger. Where is the problem at ?

Thanks in advance.

Cemo

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that there are no errors in your code? I know this sounds like a stupid (and potentially insulting) question, but the only time I've had this sort of problem is when the code hasn't compiled and I haven't noticed.

Other things to possibly check (in the absence of more information):

- Is the exe still in use when you build and hence not overwritten the first time?
- Do you have a post build step that's failing (possibly because a file is in use)?